# How to draw a dashed line across two subplots with Python?

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

time = np.linspace(-1,5, 100)

fig, (ax1, ax2, ax3) = plt.subplots(3,1, sharex=True, figsize=(5,5))
ax1.plot([-1,0,0,5], [1,1,0,0], color='navy')
ax1.set_ylim(-0.1,1.2)
ax2.plot(time, np.clip(np.exp(-time),0,1), color='darkolivegreen')
ax2.set_ylim(-0.1,1.2)
ax3.plot(time, np.clip(np.exp(-time),0,0.4), color='darksalmon')
ax3.set_ylim(-0.1,0.8)
```

I have made three subplots and arranged them vertically (x-axis shared). Is there a convenient way to add two vertical lines `x=0` and `x=-log(0.4)` that go through all three subplots?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `axvline()`:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

time = np.linspace(-1.5, 100)

fig, (ax1, ax2, ax3) = plt.subplots(3,1, sharex=True, figsize=(5,5))
ax1.plot([-1,0,0,5], [1,1,0,0], color='navy')
ax1.set_ylim(-0.1,1.2)
ax2.plot(time, np.clip(np.exp(-time),0,1), color='darkolivegreen')
ax2.set_ylim(-0.1,1.2)
ax3.plot(time, np.clip(np.exp(-time),0,0.4), color='darksalmon')
ax3.set_ylim(-0.1,0.8)

# add vertical lines to all subplots
for ax in [ax1, ax2, ax3]:
    ax.axvline(20, c='r')
```

This gives:

[image: plot with vertical lines]

If you want the vertical line to go through the whole figure, you need to set up an additional subplot as big as the three subplots taken together and make its background transparent. Then you can draw the line in the  background subplot:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.gridspec import GridSpec

time = np.linspace(-1.5, 100)

fig = plt.figure()
gs = fig.add_gridspec(3, 2)


ax1 = fig.add_subplot(gs[0, :])
ax1.plot([-1,0,0,5], [1,1,0,0], color='navy')
ax1.set_ylim(-0.1,1.2)

ax2 = fig.add_subplot(gs[1, :], sharex = ax1)
ax2.plot(time, np.clip(np.exp(-time),0,1), color='darkolivegreen')
ax2.set_ylim(-0.1,1.2)

ax3 = fig.add_subplot(gs[2, :], sharex = ax1)
ax3.plot(time, np.clip(np.exp(-time),0,0.4), color='darksalmon')
ax3.set_ylim(-0.1,0.8)

# background axes object for plotting the vertical line
ax =  fig.add_subplot(gs[:, :], sharex = ax1)
# set background color to transparent and turn off the frame
ax.patch.set_alpha(0)
ax.axis("off")
# plot the vertical line
ax.axvline(20, c='r')

plt.show()
```

This gives:

[image: plot long vertical line]

Comment: Thank you very much! Is it possible to draw a continuous vertical line, though?

Comment: It is possible, I added it to my answer.