# Plotting with two data different time/x-axis on matplotlib?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

My aim is to generate something like this [image: aim], but my try looks like this [image: my output]

The problem is I am using two CSV data and even though their time range is the same, one of them has many time intervals like around 2399 and the other one is 73.
I'm using sharex="All" command and whatever I can found from internet as well, but it gives runtime error "Locator attempting to generate 119857 ticks ([-113.5, ..., 2383.5]), which exceeds Locator.MAXTICKS (1000)"

My output generating code is following :

```
fig, (ax1, ax2,ax3,ax4) = plt.subplots(4, 1,figsize=(10,7), sharex="all")
fig.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.2)

ax1.plot( df.time, df['B'], color='k')
ax1.plot( df.time, df['Bx'], color='r')
ax1.plot( df.time, df['By'], color='b')
ax1.plot( df.time, df['Bz'], color='g')
ax1.xaxis.grid(True,alpha=0.3)
ax1.set_ylabel('Bx,By,Bz,B[nT]')

ax2.plot(df1.time, df1['v_total'],color='k')
ax2.plot(df1.time, df1['Vx'],color='r')
ax2.plot(df1.time, df1['Vy'],color='b')
ax2.plot(df1.time, df1['Vz'],color='g')
ax2.xaxis.grid(True,alpha=0.3)
ax2.set_ylabel('Vx,Vy,Vz,V[km/s]')

ax3.plot(df1.time, df1['n'],color='k')
ax3.xaxis.grid(True,alpha=0.3)
ax3.set_ylabel('Np[1/cm^3]')

ax4.plot(df1.time, df1['T'],color='k')
ax4.xaxis.grid(True,alpha=0.3)
ax4.set_ylabel('T[k]')

minutes = mdates.MinuteLocator(byminute=np.arange(0,60,15),interval=2)
minutes_fmt = mdates.DateFormatter('%H:%M')
ax4.xaxis.set_major_locator(minutes)

ax4.xaxis.set_major_formatter(minutes_fmt)

ax4.tick_params(axis='x', labelrotation=45)

fig.suptitle('FF shock May 07 2007')
plt.savefig('WindIP.png')
plt.savefig('WindIP.pdf')
plt.show()
```

My two data are:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1uqmynE78dMM_23ITVBsdu7-5tPbnQ9gC/view?usp=sharing
https://drive.google.com/file/d/17kj8MM-agNkS22J5sRGGicdQHCK5EGYL/view?usp=sharing

I used following command to change from epoch to time

```
df['epoch'] = pd.to_datetime(df.epoch, format='%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f')
df['time'] = df['epoch'].dt.strftime('%H:%M:%S')

df1['epoch'] = pd.to_datetime(df1.epoch, format='%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f')
df1['time'] = df1['epoch'].dt.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
```

and for T value

```
m_p=1.6726219*10** -27
K_b=1.38064852*10** -23
df1['nVth']=1000*df1['V_th']
df1['T']=(df1['nVth']**2*m_p)/(2*K_b)
```

So, how to reduce ticks as well as align two time intervals and show one time interval as x-axis?
And another minor problem is how put red vertical line like in the my aim figure? I tried axvline, but no success. Thanks for your consideration and help.

Comment: I have had the same problem quite often.  I find it easiest to us `pd.merge` or `pd.concat` so that they all share the same index (for `merge` you can use `how="outer"` so that all dates will be captured).  This should solve the problem.  For the vertical line across all, you can create a `GridSpec` for the figure, then plot a line across all at once, see the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66360811/how-to-draw-a-dashed-line-across-two-subplots-with-python).  Hopefully this helps; let me know if you have any questions!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you elaborate more like how can I implement pd.merge in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moving to an answer so I can write more clearly, you can merge the dataframes like this (taking from your question that `epoch` is the same in both and `pd.to_datetime()` has already been applied):

```py
df_merged = df.set_index("epoch").merge(df1.set_index("epoch"),
                                        left_index=True, right_index=True,
                                        how="outer")
```

Then using `df_merged.index` as the x-axis, and `df_merged["B"]` etc. as the columns, everything should align.  *(EDIT: thinking this through, it might be easier to merge on the `time` column, as this will not be so specific, so will not create duplicate rows for the two dataframes for the same day.)*

Then again for the line across all charts, the answer from @bb1 [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66360811/how-to-draw-a-dashed-line-across-two-subplots-with-python) gives the answer, by using:

```
gs = fig.add_gridspec(3, 2)

# ...

# background axes object for plotting the vertical line
ax =  fig.add_subplot(gs[:, :], sharex = ax1)
# set background color to transparent and turn off the frame
ax.patch.set_alpha(0)
ax.axis("off")
# plot the vertical line
ax.axvline(20, c='r')
```

You can play around with this to get it to suit your specific requirements.  You can easily duplicate the last line and use `ls="--"` to plot the dashed lines too!

Comment: When I use df3 = pd.merge(df, df1, left_index=True, right_index=True) the small interval data is guiding the x-axis, and when I use yours, the big data interval is guiding, but it gives me 'value' must be an instance of str or bytes, not a float error. I guess it is because epoch is following everything value. For example when I write df_merged['B'], it gives me B value along with epoch, not separately. How to solve this?

Comment: Well, I found a way, just use outer in this case. Thanks